# "Got a SIGABRT while executing native code" error while executing .NET native code in node js using mono runtime and edge.js

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, mono, edge.js

I need to call a function inside dll file in node js. I am trying to use edge.js for that in ubuntu 15.04.

I installed mono using the instruction given on following url:

Then I installed edge using:

```
npm install edge
```

I am trying to call a function in dll. For this i included the dll using following nodejs code:

```
var ed = require('edge').func('Sample.dll');
```

but it is throwing following error:

```
Error: No managed allocator, but we need one for AOT.
Are you using non-standard GC options?

Stacktrace:

  at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
  at System.Globalization.CultureInfo..cctor () <0x00014>
  at (wrapper runtime-invoke) object.runtime_invoke_void (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <0x00062>
  at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
  at System.IO.FileNotFoundException.SetMessageField () <0x00071>
  at System.IO.FileNotFoundException.get_Message () <0x0000c>
  at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_object__this__ (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <0x00069>

Native stacktrace:

/usr/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.so.1(+0xdac0d) [0x7f527a291c0d]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x10d10) [0x7f527ad54d10]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x37) [0x7f527a9af267]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x16a) [0x7f527a9b0eca]
/usr/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.so.1(+0x26c1e9) [0x7f527a4231e9]
/usr/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.so.1(+0x26c3f7) [0x7f527a4233f7]
/usr/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.so.1(+0x26c4a2) [0x7f527a4234a2]
/usr/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.so.1(+0xc6170) [0x7f527a27d170]
/usr/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.so.1(+0xc91f4) [0x7f527a2801f4]
/usr/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.so.1(+0xcfefb) [0x7f527a286efb]
/usr/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.so.1(+0xdccdd) [0x7f527a293cdd]
[0x4062ec15]

Debug info from gdb:

No threads.

=================================================================

Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================

Aborted (core dumped)
```